# Where can I download Google Chrome 67.0.3396.79 for Mac?

Tags: google-chrome

I am desperately trying to download this version of Chrome. Do you know where I could download this exact version of Chrome?

Version: Google Chrome 67.0.3396.79 for Mac
Date: June, 7th 2018

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Here we go, you got this. I hope this work.
https://filehippo.com/es/mac/download_google_chrome_for_mac/85180/